# Error: while importing a wordpress theme demo

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error message in my apache log while importing a wordpress theme demo.

```
[:error] [pid 1045043] [client xx.xx.91.138:21041] php: magick/cache.c:3414: GetVirtualPixels: Assertion `image->signature == 0xabacadabUL' failed., referer: http://www.example.at/wp-admin/themes.php?page=stm_demo_import
```

I have already increased php memory limit and max_execution time, but no luck

```
server : WHM 56.0
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following rule to .htacces file and it fixed the issue

```
SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1
```